# Question repoening

Tags: support, moderators

Good time of the day! In [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/15345/windows-10-build-16241-64-bit-tor-fails-to-run) question it seems to be a fake Tor/TorBrowser distribution - I used to help one person before with the same problem. The question is put on hold, but I think I'll be able to help the Asker. How to add the answer in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to get votes for 'reopen'. 
Or a mod has to open the question.
I have opened the question back up so that you can answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll post my answer then as usual! It's a dangerous signs that the very same situation appears again - fake tor distributions are becoming more actively pushed to non-IT-expert users

Comment: answer posted! I hope the problem will be solved!